# How to match value sent by ajax call in a Rails controller and display an error message?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, bootstrap-modal

```rb
<%= form_for(@mymodel, remote: true, html: { id: 'match_form' }) do |f| %>
        <!-- I need to check if @mymodel.match_id matches the value generated by a controller function -->
   <%= f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-primary', id: 'match_submit', style: "width:38px;padding:0px" %> 
   <%= button_tag 'Cancel', class: 'btn btn-secondary', id: 'match_cancel', style: "width:52px;padding:0px" %>
<% end%>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function() {
      $(document).on("click", "#match_submit", function(event){
        $.ajax('my_controller_method', {
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: 'script',
          data: {
            mid: $("#").val(),  // how do I pass @mymodel.match_id here?
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          return console.log("AJAX Error: " + textStatus);
        }
      });      
    });
  </script>
```

I have a form as shown above.

1. How do I pass @mymodel.match_id in the ajax call above?
2. In my controller function, I would like to check if passed match_id is a certain value; if not, I would like to display a modal with an error message and just an `Ok` button. How can I achieve this? 
   < > a) Should I return the correct value from controller function and check the same in my javascript code above and show a javascript alert? 
      < > < > i) If yes, then how can I return a number from a controller function to my JavaScript invoking function? 
   or 
   < > b) would I be able to render a bootstrap modal with an `Ok` button in my controller itself?

### UPDATE 1:

I tried this to pass `match_id` and `id` from `mymodel` to the ajax call but it did not work:

```rb
$(document).on("click", "#match_submit", function(event){
      alert ("match id changed!");
      alert($("#match_form").data('id'));
      alert($("#match_form").data('match_id'));

      $.ajax('cpl_evaluate_match_id', {
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'script',
        data: {
          debit_id: $("#match_form").data('id'),
          match_id: $("#match_form").data('match_id')
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        return console.log("AJAX Error: " + textStatus);
      }
      });      
    });
```

The alerts to print `id` and `match_id` print `undefined` in the alert messages.

### UPDATE 2:

I tried this to return a number from my controller function but this doesn't seem to work either:

```rb
  def evaluate_match_id
    puts params[:debit_id]
    puts params[:match_id]

    return 1
  end
```

the puts above turn up  blank

```rb
    $(document).on("click", "#match_submit", function(event){
      alert ("match id changed!");
      alert($("#match_form").data('id'));
      alert($("#match_form").data('match_id'));

      $.ajax('cpl_evaluate_match_id', {
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'script',
        data: {
          debit_id: $("#match_form").data('id'),
          match_id: $("#match_form").data('match_id')
        },
        success: function(result){
                    if(result){ // yes or no? 1 or 0, it's the return coming from your controller
            alert('true');
            alert(result);
          }
          else{
            alert('error');
            alert(result);
          }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        return console.log("AJAX Error: " + textStatus);
      }
      });      
    });
```

The value of `result` in the `success:` block in the JavaScript code above comes up as `undefined` (my controller function blindly returns the number `1` which I was expecting to be the value of `result` here). So the `if(result)` condition fails and the `else` block gets called instead.

Comment: It seems like the id is match_form

Answer (score 1):

You can use the attr to get the value element in jquery. something like this

```
$('#match_form').attr('id')
```

Answer (score 1):

some ideas coming from PHP, no exp from ruby-on-rails.

can you pass the @mymodel.match_id in an 'attribute' of your html?

```
<form data-match_id='@mymodel.match_id'...
or
<form custom_name='@mymodel.match_id' ...
```

or similar. then, you can use that on ajax to to call the form's data
via Jquery:

```
$("#match_form").data('match_id')
or
$("#match_form").attr('custom_name')
```

on your second question, you should have a success function on your ajax, that will return the contents recieved from your controller.

```
$.ajax({url: "my_controller_method", 
data: {
    mid: $("#match_form").data('match_id'),
}
success: function(result){
if(result) // yes or no? 1 or 0, it's the return coming from your controller
    alert('true');
else
    alert('error');
}});
```

from your controller, you should display the return value instead of just return. (like when you accessed your controller, it will be a white screen with just the return value like 1 or 0)

Lastly, yes you can, or better if you can create a predefined messages for modal ready on your view, and just invoke which message will show on modal.

UPDATE 1:
to properly get the desired attribute on the form, first you need to get the form element properly, on either adding ID or any other method.

```
<form id="match_form" data-match_id="your_value_here">
```

from here, you can get the data attribrute 'match_id' using this jquery syntax

```
var match_id = $("#match_form").data('match_id');
console.log(match_id);
```

you can try this code on your browser's console (F12 on modern browsers Chrome/Firefox), and it should output your_value_here

on Update 2, you might need to output it, try displaying the number '1' on your controller, then try the ajax, the result will be the number '1'.

hope this answers your question.

Comment: This answer was certainly helpful; but the suggestion for the way to pass `id` and `match_id` seems incorrect. I have added `UPDATE 1` in my original question with my findings for this suggestion. Pls help!

Comment: The `success:` block of JavaScript code above gets called fine but the value of `result` shows up as `undefined`. Please refer `UPDATE 2:` in my original question for my findings on this.

Comment: Hello Biju, i tried to help using my PHP knowledge as i don't have any exp on ruby-on-rails. but as far as JQuery is concerned, i think what you need is to identify your form's ID to get the desired attribute. i will update my answer now.

Comment: Thanks. As I said your answer was CERTAINLY helpful. Any further help would be great!!